# PHP namespace: "fall back to global" WITHIN CODE?

Tags: php, namespaces

If one uses namespaces AND as the namespace statement needs to be the first code statement, is there a way (in the very same file) to "fall back" into global space as you can go into other namespaces (and back to any) using the "namespace" keyword?

I know that I could include another file at any point and in that file, which would fall back to global, but I explicitly want to know - I write some own parsing code - IF that is possible WITHIN the SAME file at all)

I tried all namespace statements I could think of for the global space but with no success. So, what I would search for:

[CODE START]

```
namespace SPACE1;

class declarations;

namespace SPACE2;

class declarations;

namespace [GLOBAL];
```

class declarations that will go into global namespace;

```
namespace SPACE3;

class declarations;
```

[CODE END]

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use brackets to combine global non-namespaced code with namespaced code:

```php
namespace SPACE1 {
  // namespace declarations
}

namespace SPACE2 {
  // namespace declarations
}

namespace {
  // global declarations
}
```

For more information:

> To combine global non-namespaced code with namespaced code, only bracketed syntax is supported. Global code should be encased in a namespace statement with no namespace name as in

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php#example-297

Comment: Thanks for your answer & sorry I did not mention in my question, that I know abot the curly brackets use case and in my test I found that it's possible there.

I explicitly wanted to know if it's also possible if the "normal" namespace statement is being used as I try to parse some code (from others) and I wanted to be sure THAT ITS NOT POSSIBLE, so i have not to deal with this possibility in my code.

Comment: @jwka Ah, I understand. I have tried a few things and read the documentation, but didn't come across a solution without braces

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time spent to help! Much appreciated! As of now I "believe" there's no possibility to fall back without the use of curly brackets. So, I will not spend more time to deal with that "exception". So, I guess this answer can be marked "solved",